# Group by month and counting rows for current and all previous months

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by

PostgreSQL 13

Assuming a simplified table `plans` like the following, it can be assumed that there is at least 1 row for every month and sometimes multiple rows on the same day:

| `id` | `first_published_at` |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678910 | 2022-10-01 03:58:55.118 |
| abcd1234efg | 2022-10-03 03:42:55.118 |
| jhsdf894hld | 2022-10-03 17:34:55.118 |
| aslb83nfys5 | 2022-09-12 08:17:55.118 |

My simplified query:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(plans.first_published_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS publication_date, COUNT(*)
FROM plans
WHERE plans.first_published_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(plans.first_published_at, 'YYYY-MM');
```

This gives me the following result:

| `publication_date` | `count` |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10 | 3 |
| 2022-09 | 1 |

But the result I would need for October is `4`.

For every month, the count should be an aggregation of the current month and ALL previous months. I would appreciate any insight on how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use your query as a CTE and run a select that uses cumulative `sum` as a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html).

```sql
with t as
(
 SELECT TO_CHAR(plans.first_published_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS publication_date, 
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
 FROM plans
 WHERE plans.first_published_at IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY publication_date
)
select publication_date, 
       sum(cnt) over (order by publication_date) as "count"
from t
order by publication_date desc;
```

Demo on [DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bfGut1KYRtW5pFuVBVn5tT/0)

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed! I'll have to look into window functions more